# TabView app that pushes and pops views within a tab

Tags: ios, view, tabs, subview, tabbarcontroller

This is the second time I am asking this question but I do feel a bit more experience and maybe could word it better this time.

I have an iPhone app that has 3 tabs, the delegate has a tabBarController and the 3 views that appear on the screen for each tab are controlled by "FirstViewController", "SecondViewController" and "ThirdViewController" respectively.

The second and third views are all sorted.

Right so here is my question. In the first tab I have 20 UIButton's that are all connected to their respective IBOutlet buttons and methods in the first view controller. At the moment I have each method just hiding all information on the screen so I could in theory unhide information such as a textbox when they are pressed but this gets very messy in the IB.

Essentially I would like each button, when pressed, to bring forward a new screen/view that has its own .xib file that I could put all information on including a back button (another UIButton) that when pressed destorys the current screen and returns back to tabA's original view.

How would this be done?

I did try creating a new class, a UIView class that comes with its own .xib. I then in one of the methods set 3 lines of code that basically setup the new view with .xib then add it as a subview. this worked fine and brought the new screen forward however I was unable to remove this specific subview to return to the original view.

Thank you for any help.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "E87view.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIButton *E87, *E81, *F20, *E36, *E46, *E90,
                    *E34, *E39, *E60, *E63, *E64, *E38,
*E65, *F01, *X3, *X5, *Z3, *Z4, *M3, *M5, *backButton;

IBOutlet UILabel *ones, *threes, *fives, *sixs, *sevens, *xs, *zs, *ms;

IBOutlet UITextView *mainText;

}

-(IBAction) E87Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E81Pressed; 
-(IBAction) F20Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E36Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E46Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E90Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E34Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E39Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E60Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E63Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E64Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E38Pressed; 
-(IBAction) E65Pressed; 
-(IBAction) F01Pressed; 
-(IBAction) X3Pressed; 
-(IBAction) X5Pressed; 
-(IBAction) Z3Pressed; 
-(IBAction) Z4Pressed; 
-(IBAction) M3Pressed; 
-(IBAction) M5Pressed; 
-(IBAction) backButtonPressed;

-(void) hideAll;
-(void) showAll;

@end
```

And the .m file. Obviously pay no attention to the hidden elements in the hide and show methods. Obviously I dont want to use this method I wanna push and pop new screens. Keeping my tabs

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "E87view.h"


@implementation FirstViewController


-(void) hideAll{
E87.hidden = 1;
E81.hidden = 1;
F20.hidden = 1;
E36.hidden = 1;
E46.hidden = 1;
E90.hidden = 1;
E34.hidden = 1;
E39.hidden = 1;
E60.hidden = 1;
E63.hidden = 1;
E64.hidden = 1;
E38.hidden = 1;
E65.hidden = 1;
F01.hidden = 1;
X3.hidden = 1;
X5.hidden = 1;
Z3.hidden = 1;
Z4.hidden = 1;
M3.hidden = 1;
M5.hidden = 1;
ones.hidden = 1;
threes.hidden = 1;
fives.hidden = 1;
sixs.hidden = 1;
sevens.hidden = 1;
xs.hidden = 1;
zs.hidden = 1;
ms.hidden = 1;
mainText.hidden = 1;
backButton.hidden = 0;
}

-(void) showAll{
E87.hidden = 0;
E81.hidden = 0;
F20.hidden = 0;
E36.hidden = 0;
E46.hidden = 0;
E90.hidden = 0;
E34.hidden = 0;
E39.hidden = 0;
E60.hidden = 0;
E63.hidden = 0;
E64.hidden = 0;
E38.hidden = 0;
E65.hidden = 0;
F01.hidden = 0;
X3.hidden = 0;
X5.hidden = 0;
Z3.hidden = 0;
Z4.hidden = 0;
M3.hidden = 0;
M5.hidden = 0;
ones.hidden = 0;
threes.hidden = 0;
fives.hidden = 0;
sixs.hidden = 0;
sevens.hidden = 0;
xs.hidden = 0;
zs.hidden = 0;
ms.hidden = 0;
mainText.hidden = 0;
}

-(IBAction) backButtonPressed{
[self showAll];
backButton.hidden = 1;
//[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {

//  [subview removeFromSuperview];
//}
//[self showAll];


}

-(IBAction) E87Pressed{
[self hideAll];
//E87view *e87view = [[E87view alloc] initWithNibName:@"E87view" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:e87view animated:YES];
//[self.view addSubview:e87view.view];
}


// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    [self showAll];
}
[self showAll];
return self;
}



// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {

[self showAll];
}



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//backButton.hidden = 1;
[self showAll];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackdropService.png"]];
backButton.hidden = 1;


}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation     {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Of course I have a new .h and .m called E87view which has its own .xib file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed `FirstViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and use:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:theButtonController animated:YES];
```

and then use the back button that is created on the navigation bar or get rid of the navigation bar and create your own back button using:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This method would keep your tabs present at the bottom.

If you don't care about keeping your tabs present then you can use a `modalViewController` like so:

```
[self presentModalViewController:theModalController animated:YES];
```

I would then create a protocol in `theModalController` that would call back to the `FirstViewController` when it was completed.  The `FirstViewController` would then use this code to dismiss the `theModalController`:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So two ways to go.  Use a `UINavigationController` if you want to keep your tabs and just push `viewController`s onto the stack.  If you don't care about keeping the tabs when you use these new `viewController`s then you can use `modalViewController` above and they will take over the entire screen.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:  This is how you can set up the navigation controller, You will need to `#import` the `.h` file for each of the `viewControllers` in your `AppDelegate.h`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    FirstViewController* vc1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController* vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    ThirdViewController* vc3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:vc1];

    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, vc2, vc3, nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

After that, FirstViewController will be embedded in a `UINavigationController` and can use the pop and push code that I used above.

Comment: Do you think you could get on Skype with me later tonight? In say, 2 hours time? 

Wont take us long, I am more of a "Monkey See, Monkey Do" type of learner. For example I am not sure what you mean by embed FirstViewController in a UINavigationController. Do you mean in the interface file add <UINavigationController> kind of like inheritance?

Comment: I will not be available for skype, but are you using a storyboard by chance?

Comment: Nope I am using Xcode 3.2 lol. I aint bought Lion because ya know, it isn't my MAC. But I have updated my post to include the code so if you wanted to repost the code with your solution included that would be grand.

Comment: Try this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html

Comment: I can't follow that. What did you mean by embed FirstViewController in a UINavigationController and use:

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:theButtonController animated:YES];
and then use the back button that is created on the navigation bar or get rid of the navigation bar and create your own back button using:

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
This method would keep your tabs present at the bottom.

I think I would like to use this method.

Comment: do you create your tabbarcontroller in the app delegate?  If so, post your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` code above.

Comment: I do indeed, in the .h it is declared then in the implementation file it is there, added as a subview. This is how it was from the template.

Comment: post the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and I'll edit it to use navigationControllers

Comment: Done, although it is applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. That alright?

Comment: Where do the views get set up for `tabBarController`?  Where does it get created?

Comment: I select the tab entry in interface builder and set the view controllers in the identity tab. So the 3 tabs work fine this way. I just want now in tab A where I have 20 UIButtons to each push a new view with my info on with a back button to return back to tab A's original view. I would like to keep the tab bars there.

Comment: I notice you are asking me to instansiate all my views, will this effect of current setup in interface builder? I see how you are making navController = the first view. Where is "window" and the "MyViewController1/2/3" declared? I assume "FirstViewController1" is referring to the controllers I setup?

Comment: I edited it with the correct names, sorry about that.  Actually, did you name the nib files in your iterface builder?  If you did you can use `initWithNibName:` instead of just `init`.  Like `FirstViewController *vc1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Right it looks like it makes sense, I assum all the push and pop code I been seeing for the views will work after I use this code. Where is "window" declared? Not in front of my MAC at the moment. Looking forward to trying your solution though. Ummm I only have a main and first view nib and then my own nib I created. Not sure how that works since I have 3 tabs all using their own screen controlled by their own controllers but effectively only the 2 nibs that come with the tab bar app template. I know "first view.xib" is the first tab but the 2nd and 3rd tabs have no nibs.

Comment: You should have assigned them a "Nib Name" in the inspector.  And yes, after this you can use the push and pop code on the firstviewcontroller

Comment: Oh is window already part of the class. Was just looking at my delegate code and self.window is there so....Also I ticked your answer since its the best one I have seen. It's just about practice at the end of the day I will get there. Thank you for being patient with me. Ever need WP7 advice just tap me up.

Comment: Okay will keep that in mind, hope this works out for you.  It may be easiest to create a seperate nib for each of your tabs instead of using the main for the first view, it works either way though.  You also may want to look at upgrading and using iOS 5.0 because storyboards and segues make this 100000x easier.

Comment: The comments section is not to be used as an interactive debug session.